# Animated GIF are not working in Microsoft Teams Snippet Previews

Tags: microsoft-teams

When Microsoft Teams (no matter desktop or web) creates a preview of an URL (the snippet), if in the metatags the image is an animated gif, the result is corrupted.

Microsoft Teams is using this internal service to create that thumbnail:

[https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/image/Thumbnail?url={the_url_of_the_gif}](https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/image/Thumbnail?url=%7Bthe_url_of_the_gif%7D)

And no matter the GIF I tried, all of them results in a corrupted preview:

https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/image/Thumbnail?url=https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/7CLk.gif

I don't know the methods used in that "Thumbnail" method because it's a private API of Skype (part of Microsoft).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I do need to use GIF for URL preview. I know I could code an extension an create my own kind of snippet, but it's not applicable, I can not tell users to install any extension.

I'd like to solve the GIF conversion corruption this API method could have ... maybe it's something about the headers of the GIF, or the palette, or ...

Any ideas ?

More weird thing is that, SAME FILE (different URL for avoiding cache), sometimes the previewer (the urlp.asm.skype...) shows it well (5% of times), and rest shows the dirty snow ... so it's not about the palette or config of the gif, but some specific conversion inside the "Thumbnail" process of Skype API

Comment: We have tested this using following sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-link-unfurling/csharp

We have used https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/image/Thumbnail? GIF URL and its working fine in URL preview also. Please refer below video
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/228750794-13bdb5bb-2ff6-4f45-8cea-f890462f5878.webm

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT   Precisely in that video you generated you can see the corrupted gif also, hehehehe. Have you seen the original one? ... see it !! don't you notice the "grey/dark snow" in the top of the first frames (vanishing as video plays) ? You have the same bug in your environment ... I'm glad to hear that ! ;-)

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT take any other gif in Internet ... you will see always that "glitch" of snow in the first frames ... if you didn't notice in the post one, take this: https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/image/Thumbnail?url=https://i0.wp.com/www.printmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/4cbe8d_f1ed2800a49649848102c68fc5a66e53mv2.gif

Comment: More weird thing is that, SAME FILE (different URL for avoiding cache), sometimes the previewer (the urlp.asm.skype...) shows it well (5% of times), and rest shows the dirty snow ... so it's not about the palette or config of the gif, but some specific conversion inside the "Thumbnail" process of Skype API

Comment: Tested with another gif. Its working fine at our end. Not abke to see any grey/dark snow.
Please refer video: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/229126396-d967e94a-bc6c-4792-b00e-3dc26cfd7f1f.webm

Comment: That's not a typical GIF, but just screenshots ... palette conversion works different in that kind of gifs ... please, take ANY gif from internet, any "meme", anything from giphy ...

Comment: Taking gif from giffy. Video was not currupted. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/229458062-85e475eb-c637-4ea9-b2f6-701a759e21a8.webm
Original gif : http://www.reactiongifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/running.gif

Comment: Could you please try with above gif and check once its working or not?